# C# Compiler thinks these variables should be initialized

Tags: c#

Here is a sample of an application that I'm writing:

```
        bool x3k = false, y3k = false;

        // all of these functions return nullable ints (int?)
        var comparison = 
            DoSomething(x, y)
            ?? DoSomething2(x, y)
            ?? DoSomething3(x, y, out x3k, out y3k)
            ?? DoSomething4(x, y)
            ?? DoSomething5(x, y);

        if (comparison.HasValue)
            return comparison.Value;

        if (x3k) // compiler error here if I don't init x3k
        {

        }
```

I don't understand, in the null coalescing chain, how x3k could be uninitialized if `comparison` is `null` and I don't return early. What's going on here?

Comment: If `DoSomething` returns non-null, how is `DoSomething3` ever going to be invoked? If `DoSomething3` is not invoked, how are those variables initialized? Null coalescing is short-circuiting.

Comment: Except, there's explicit initialization at the top.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: "if I don't init x3k"

Answer (score 5):

You are encountering short-circuit behavior: If `DoSomething` or `DoSomething2` return something non-null, `DoSomething3` will never execute, thus leaving `x3k` and `y3k` uninitialized.

Comment: In the case that `DoSomething` or `DoSomething2` return non-null values, `x3k` and `y3k` are never accessed since I'm returning early if there's a non-null value.

Comment: @FMM The compiler is not that smart.

Comment: Compiler can't assume that ahead of time

Comment: A compiler is can check for finitely many items http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx

Comment: In the code above, x3k and y3k are initialized to false.

Comment: @feO2x Note the "compiler error here **if I don't init x3k**" comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is expanded by the compiler into this:

```
bool x3k;
bool y3k;
var comparison = DoSomething(x, y);
if (!comparison) {
 comparison = DoSomething2(x, y);
 if (!comparison) {
  comparison = DoSomething3(x, y, out x3k, out y3k);
  if (!comparison) {
   comparison = DomeSomething4(x, y);
   if (!comparison) {
    comparison = DoSomething5(x, y);
   }
  }
 }
}
if (comparison.HasValue) return comparison.value;
if (x3k) {/* ... */}
```

The `if` nest will be broken out of as soon as one of the functions returns something non-null. If `DoSomething3` does not run, `x3k` is not initialized. `comparison.HasValue` will be `true` as soon as one of the functions returns non-null, but the compiler treats that property as something not determinable at compile time. Therefore, it thinks `comparison` could be null and `x3k` to not be initialized.

Comment: If `comparison` is non-`null`, `x3k` never gets accessed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. The post has been edited.

Comment: This answer explained it pretty well for me.